# No synced vagrant folder to be found

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to work through the "Getting Started" section at the vagrant [site](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/).  I run through the two commands they show:

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
$ vagrant up
```

All seems to go well. I then run these two commands:

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ lsb_release -a
```

The result shows I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04, precise. So far so good.

However, when I do an 'ls' the only thing in the directory is a postinstall.sh file.  I thought I should have been in the same directory as the Vagrantfile.

Sorry for such a newbie question. I'm sure its something basic I messed up.

I'm doing this on an Ubuntu 14.10 box with Virtualbox 4.3.22 and Vagrant 1.7.2 installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Vagrant will share your project directory (the directory with the Vagrantfile) to `/vagrant` on the guest machine.

Comment: Yes, that's how I understand it, but then shouldn't I be able to see the Vagrant file and other folders in my project in `/vagrant` on the guest machine?  All I see is a `postinstall.sh` file. Should I run this file?  Thanks

Comment: @user1791991,when you type `vagrant ssh` you are logged in under vagrant's home folder (`/home/vagrant`).  You then need to type `cd /vagrant` and do an `ls` to get to the project directory.